# Download pictures from a specific website in C#

Tags: c#, database, image, tags

I want to download lot of pictures from a specific website, but the pictures have different URLs (I mean they are not like something.com/picture1 then something.com/picture2)  If it helps, I want to download from the EA's FUT card database, but I have no idea how should I do this.

Comment: You can parse the response for <img> tags to get the url and download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML Agility pack to Parse every `<img>` from the response and get the source attribute.

Then you can loop through the image tags and download the image via. HttpClient, as you did with the webpage.

This would look something like this (`response` is the html returned by the web-request):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(response);
foreach(HtmlNode imageSrc in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img/@src")
{
   //Use node.Value to download the picture here     
}
```

Get more infos about the html Agility Pack here:
http://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot with this project!

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe you can mark my answer so other will see this too. Thx